# Firebase Database retrieve data Issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have put a button in my App. When I press the button +1 value saves to my database. So I want to check a method that when the button `count =5` show an alert.It checks when i click the button. When my button `count =5` alert shows 3-4 times. But I want to show it for 1 time :(

Here is the code :

```
private void ButtonChecker(){
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ezzeearnRef = rootRef.child(User1);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Long BRef1 = dataSnapshot.child("BRef").getValue(Long.class);
                assert BRef1 != null;
                int x = BRef1.intValue( );
                ref = x;
                if (x ==5){
                    showAlert("Don't CLick Button ");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        ezzeearnRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're registering a new listener every time that the user presses the button. If the initial value is `3`, the user has to press the button twice to get it to `5`. That means your code registers two listeners and thus shows two alerts.

Two solutions:

- Only register a listener once.
- Register listeners that only get the current value.

#### Register listeners that only get the current value

This is the simplest change: we'll register a listener that:

1. Reads the current value
2. Automatically unregisters itself

The only change is how you register the listener:

```
ezzeearnRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

But this still registers/unregisters a listener for every click, which can be a bit wasteful. In addition: if you ever make your app multi-user, this misses the fact that other users may be incrementing the counter too.

#### Only register a listener once

Whenever possible, register and unregister your listeners in activity-lifecycle methods. For example, it is quite common to register the listeners in `onStart` and unregister them in `onStop`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ezzeearnRef = rootRef.child(User1);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Long BRef1 = dataSnapshot.child("BRef").getValue(Long.class);
            assert BRef1 != null;
            int x = BRef1.intValue( );
            ref = x;
            if (x ==5){
                showAlert("Don't CLick Button ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    };
    ezzeearnRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ezzeearnRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
}
```

With this code your listener will be active during the lifecycle of the activity. During that time, if the counter (is or) becomes 5, the alert will show once.

Comment: if I declare it in OnStart it will show when app starts. But I don't want this in OnStart. I want it should works when the button is clicked 

Comment: In that case you can  use the first option I gave to prevent the handler from triggering multiple times.

Comment: addListenerForSingleValueEvent doesn't works properly.

Comment: And When i try to implements OnStop is shows error.

Comment: Frank??  How can I declare onStop?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime firebase call for data multiple time so you will get same x value more then one time. to fix this use a boolean variable which store value about alert.

```
 boolean isAlertShown = false;

private void ButtonChecker(){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ezzeearnRef = rootRef.child(User1);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Long BRef1 = dataSnapshot.child("BRef").getValue(Long.class);
            assert BRef1 != null;
            int x = BRef1.intValue( );
            ref = x;
            if (x ==5 && !isAlertShown){
                 isAlertShown = true;
                showAlert("Don't CLick Button ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    ezzeearnRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}
```